# Solution to Picam(s) poor auto exposure with Motion?

Tags: raspicam, picamera, motion, video-input, picam

i've got pi-cams: v1, v1 IR, v2 NoIR, v2 IMX219-D160 wide, and none of them can dynamically adjust it's auto-exposure/brightness by itself, when used as CCTV by Motion.
they somewhat try but outputs are poor.

so far i have been manually adjusting brightness levels (15-65) in the motion.conf and restarting the daemon.

"**not-even-workaround**":

i could do a cron-job replacing motion.conf file for dusk and dawn, but times change throughout year (in places other than near Equator) and having to manually adjust cron-job on (weekly) basis would be still manual approach.

also it does **not solve** problem of **sudden change during day**, when sharp **sun** peeks between heavy **clouds**.

---

?a **solution**?:

- somehow connecting photo/light-sensor/resistor
- then trying to somehow read it's 0-255 int values in (near) real-time
- based on those, via cron-job, replacing brightness value in the motion.conf accordingly and restarting daemon

i have GPIO board and Pi 3B.

---

has anyone solved something similar already or has any better/simpler solution, please?

and if so, how?

thank you!

[funnel your energy from spell-checking into actual solution...]

Comment: Take a look at `sunwait` from https://github.com/risacher/sunwait that can give you the time for civil, nautical, astronomical (or locally managed) sunrise and sunset. It's based on your lat/long (which you can get from your GPS).

Comment: @Dougie "also it does not solve problem of sudden change during day, when sharp sun peeks between heavy clouds."